# How to install mpi4py on for Python3 on Raspberry Pi after installing MPICH?

Tags: python, software-compilation, cluster

I have installed MPICH on my Pi. I am making a cluster.

`sudo apt-get install python-mpi4py` installs mpi4py. However, it also install openmpi which conflicts with MPICH.

So, I started from scratch again, installed MPICH. After that I ran following sequence of commands,

`sudo apt-get install cython` installs cython which is must for mpi4py.

`git clone https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py` downloads mpi4py source.

`cd mpi4py` to open mpi4py source directory.

`sudo python3 setup.py build` to build. It shows following error,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/mpi4py $ sudo python3 setup.py build
Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
```

Someone please help me. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here. I have asked the same query on MPI4PY bitbucket portal. We can find that discussion [here](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/issues/48/mpi4py-installation-for-mpich2-on).

Go to home directory.

cd ~

Download mpi4py tarball.

wget https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/downloads/mpi4py-2.0.0.tar.gz

Update.

sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Unzip the file.

tar zxf mpi4py-2.0.0.tar.gz

Open the directory.

cd mpi4py-2.0.0

Installation for Python3

sudo apt-get install python3-dev

sudo python3 setup.py build --mpicc=/home/pi/mpich-install/bin/mpicc

sudo python3 setup.py install

Installation for Python

sudo apt-get install python-dev

sudo python setup.py build --mpicc=/home/pi/mpich-install/bin/mpicc

sudo python setup.py install